# Java UDP packets received as Junk characters

Tags: java, udp

i have written a simple UDP server program which receives data packets from a network controller(Aruba) but prints the output junk characters as below. Tried setting character Set to UTF-8 but didnt help.

```
    public class UDPServer
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
         DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9999);
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[2048];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[2048];
            while(true)
               {
                  DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                  serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                  String response = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, 
                          receivePacket.getLength(), "UTF-8");

                  System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + response);
               }
      }
}
```

output :

```
RECEIVED: ï¿½ï¿½drÈï¿½Zï¿½ï¿½ï¿]Ð¾ï¿½,E!ï¿Uoï¿½¿½ï¿½fï¿½`ï¿½
RECEIVED: ï¿½(drÈ$wï¿½D ï¿½ï¿½kï¿½Oï¿½ï¿½ï¿½?ï¿½NQï¿½ï¿½
pECEIVED: ï¿½ï¿½drÈï¿½ï¿½.Oï¿½dLIï¿½,Oï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½uï¿½
VT102RECEIVED: ï¿½Ddrï¿½ï¿½aï¿½cdï¿½ï¿½ï¿½k0ï¿½ï¿½-ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Iï¿½Q
RECEIVED: ï¿½drï¿½ï¿½ï¿½Vï¿½ï¿½ï¿½;;kï¿½ï¿½
$oï¿½ï¿½ï¿½
ECEIVED: ï¿½^
```

Comment: No evidence of a problem here. What was sent?

Comment: There appears to be a 4 byte repeating pattern. I would try print out the bytes in hexidecimal to try to determine what was sent.